# Label displaying (null) how to remove (null) from lable

Tags: nsstring, null, uilabel

I assigned some (value) to label by using some string variable.

When string variable returning value label showing the same value . but when string is not returning any value label displaying (null).

so i want to not to show anything in label if string variable is not returning anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if([label.text isequaltostring:@"null"])
```

**OR**

```
string.length==0;
```

**OR**

```
string.text==nil
```

**then put**

```
label.text=@"";
```